# Java-Eclipse-Spring 3.1 - the fastest way to get familiar with this set

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I, know almost all of you at some point of your life as a programmer get to the point where you know (more or less) different technologies/languages/IDEs and a times come when you want to get things together and start using them once - more efficient and second - more closely to the real life situation where in fact just knowing Java, or some experience with Eclipse doesn't mean nothing, and what makes you a programmer worth something is the ability to work with the combination of 2 or more combinations.

Having this in mind here is my question - what do you think is the optimal way of getting into Java+Eclipse+Spring3.1 world. I've read, and I've read a lot. I started writing real code but almost every step is discovering the wheel again and again, wondering how to do thing you know are some what trivial, but you've missed that one article where this topic was discussed and so on. I don't mind for paying for a good tutorial like for example, after a bit of research I decided that instead of losing a lot of time getting the different parts together I'd rather pay for the videos in `http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/starting-in-symfony2-tutorial` and save myself a lot of time (I hope) and get as fast as possible to writing a real code instead of wondering what do what and so on.

But I find it much more difficult to find such sources of info especially when you want something more specific as me and that's the reason to ask this question. I know a lot of you go through the hard way, and I won't give up if I have to do the same, but to be honest I really hope to get post with good tutorials on the subject (paid or not) because in my situation time is literally money.

Thanks

Leron

Comment: This should probably go on programmers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Get SpringSource Toolsuite, an Eclipse based IDE from the makers of Spring: http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts
2. Familiarize yourself with Maven, you'll need it to build and test projects (it has Eclipse integration as well).
3. On GitHub you can find a lot of useful "example" projects made from SpringSource, download them and learn from the code - it's clean and concise. Here are some interesting ones:
4. a) https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase (using [Spring
   MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html))

   b) https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mobile-samples (using
   [Spring Mobile](http://www.springsource.org/spring-mobile))

   c) https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples (using
   [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social))

   d) https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa-examples (using
   [Spring Data JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa))

and more...

As you can see, these example projects demonstrate different possibilities Spring provides, and they are realized/implemented using different Spring modules (there are lots of them, check the official Spring page). All of them use Spring Core module.

You only have to choose what to learn first, depending on your needs and start from there. A good example is Spring MVC and after that Spring Data JPA. With those covered you can make a pretty decent web application.

If you want a book, Manning Spring in Action (the newest edition) is very good for beginners in Spring and has lot's of useful information.

P.S. If you haven't used Maven, here's how you import one of the SpringSource example projects in STS: Download the project, unzip it if you downloaded the archive, go in STS in Project -> Import and choose Existing Maven project and browse to the location in which the pom.xml file in the unzipped project is. In almost every example project you can see a README.md file with instructions on how to run it.

And last but not least, follow the [official Spring Blog](http://blog.springsource.org/). They post announcement of new versions of Spring and it's sub-module projects, and post examples as well.

Update:

A mention is worthy of the 5-part tutorial series '[Building a RESTful Web Service with Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/25/building-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-3-1-and-java-based-configuration-part-2/)' an of the 6-part [Spring Data tutorial](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/01/spring-data-jpa/) series which cover pretty much everything from JPA to Graph Databases (Neo4J) and document stores (MongoDB) and key-value stores (Redis).

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of answers I was expecting. Really appreciated.